# From ajax call, setting session value in code behind gives error message

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, web-services, session

At page load in code behind, the setting of session value working fine. **But from the ajax call**, it gives the **error message** as `Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the <configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration.`

SessionData is `Public Property SessionData(sessionVariableName As String) As String`
Codebehind:

```
SessionData("UserRole") = "Supervisor"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved by adding `EnableSession:=True` in the `webmethod`